# How to get rid of use-strict warning when using webpack and jshint-loader?

Tags: javascript, jshint, webpack, use-strict

I have a webpack project wired with the jshint-loader which is defined like so:

```
postLoaders: [
       {
           test: /\.js$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           loader: 'jshint-loader'
       }
],
```

and when I run webpack-dev-server I get the following warning in all of my files:

> WARNING in ./js/main.js
>   jshint results in errors
>     Use the function form of "use strict". @ line 1 char 1
>       "use strict";

I tried using the `"strict": false` option in my config file under jshint but it did not help.

Adding `'use strict'` in the files also did not help.

The only solution that I found was adding `/*jshint globalstrict: true*/` in each js file in my project...

Does someone have a solution for it in the global scope?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file called .jshintrc that defines the global settings that you want jshint to use.

This shows all the possible settings for a file
https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc

You would simply create a .jshintrc and set `globalstrict: true` in that instead of in every js file.

The config section of jshint here: http://jshint.com/docs/ has more info if you need it.

Comment: I'm aware of the .jshintrc file option, and I'm willing to use such file, but webpacks ignores it. I need somehow to tell webpack about it.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/jshint-loader/pull/8 this might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

turns out it is not that simple.

I found a great solution using eslint instead.
Here is the example project: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem just adding the `globalstrict: true` like @AR7.

the next problem was fixed: https://github.com/webpack/jshint-loader/issues/13

About your problem in the comment you can do something like this:

I decided to put the jshint config in the `package.json`, another way to setup JSHint, so that way it's easier to read the config but if you want just create a new configuration there like `jshint: { ... }` or read from the .jshint file and convert it to json.

The problem is Webpack need to knows the JSHint configuration [check here how they setup the jshint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-loader)

```
var path = require('path');
var pkg = require(path.resolve(__dirname, './package.json'));

....

module: {
  preLoaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: [
      'jshint'
    ],
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    ]
  }]
},
jshint: pkg['jshintConfig'] // This is the actually fix
```

Answer (score 1):

you must setting hint to `jshint` that you use `"use strict";` global into your files, you can use [`jshint` options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#strict) into `webpack` configuration file.

`webpack.config.js` file will be:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    module: {
      //...
      postLoaders: [
       {
           test: /\.js$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           loader: 'jshint-loader'
       }
      ] 
    },
    jshint: {
       strict: "global" // <-- adding strict mode option as global
    }
};
```